# Why my post request is pending?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have code a request, similar to others in the code, but it pends and I don't understand why.

Here is the code in the controller :

```
  $scope.addScroll = function(){
    InternDataProvider.addScroll(globalCtrl.unscrolled)
            .then(function(reports) {
                console.log("Changes saved");
                globalCtrl.scrollmessage="Combinaison "+globalCtrl.unscrolled.media+"/"+globalCtrl.unscrolled.platoform+" ajoutée.";
                globalCtrl.scrollmessageerr="";
                }).catch(function(err) {
                  console.error('Unable to fetch forecast report: ' + err);
        });
  };
```

The code in the factory part :

```
internDataProvider.addScroll = function(uscr)
{
    var httpParams = {
            unscrolled: uscr
    };


    return $http.post(addScroll, {
        params : httpParams,
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log("Successful: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

            }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err.statusCode);
    });

};
```

And the code in the node.js part :

```
//Add a combination of media or platform to the scroll
function addScroll(res, queryParams)
{
    var int1 = listMedias.indexOf(queryParams.unscrolled.media) +1;
    var int2 = listPlatforms.indexOf(queryParams.unscrolled.platform);
    connection.query("UPDATE safeplusdb.scroll SET isscrolled="+true+" WHERE idm="+int1+" AND vector_id="+int2+";", function(err, records) {
              if(err) throw err;
              console.log("UPDATE safeplusdb.scroll SET isscrolled="+true+" WHERE idm="+int1+" AND vector_id="+int2+";");
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.scroll;", function (err, records){
              if(err) throw err;

              for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
              {
                var record= records[i];
                indj=indk=0;
                if(record.isscrolled==false)
                {
                  if(record.idm==null && record.vector_id !=null)
                  {
                    listUnScroll[indj] = {media : null, platform : null};
                    listUnScroll[indj].media = null;
                    listUnScroll[indj].platform = listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
                    indj++;
                  }
                  else if(record.vector_id==null && record.idm!=null)
                  {
                    listUnScroll[indj] = {media : null, platform : null};
                    listUnScroll[indj].platform = null;
                    listUnScroll[indj].media = listMedias[record.idm-1];
                    indj++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    listUnScroll[indj] = {media : null, platform : null};
                    listUnScroll[indj].media = listMedias[record.idm-1];
                    listUnScroll[indj].platform = listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
                    indj++;  
                  }    
                }

                else if(record.isscrolled==true)
                {
                  if(record.idm==null && record.vector_id !=null)
                  {
                    listScroll[indk] = {media : null, platform : null};
                    listScroll[indk].media = null;
                    listScroll[indk].platform = listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
                    indk++;
                  }
                  else if(record.vector_id==null && record.idm!=null)
                  {
                    listScroll[indk] = {media : null, platform : null};
                    listScroll[indk].platform = null;
                    listScroll[indk].media = listMedias[record.idm-1];
                    indk++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    listScroll[indk] = {media : null, platform : null};
                    listScroll[indk].media = listMedias[record.idm-1];
                    listScroll[indk].platform = listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
                    indk++;  
                  }       
                }
              }

            });
    });
}
```

I obtain data in a HTML page, I use a controller (with Angular.js) to manipulate it and, I transmit it to my server.js file (node.js).

The request resulted, when I test it on Workbench, it works with no problem. But with this code, I have a request pending, like this :
[image: pending request]

When I stop the web application, the change executed by the request can be made.

So, how to explain the present pending ? How to solve this ?

Comment: The request is pending because it's waiting for a definite response from the server which never coming. In the server-side code, you got to send a definite reponse by calling either `res.end(definiteResponseString)` or by calling successive `res.write(responseFragmentString)` then `res.end(optionallyLastResponseFragment)`

Answer (score 6):

You're not sending a response to the request, assuming your route handler only calls this `addScroll()` function. `res` is passed to the function, but it's not used anywhere. Once you `res.end();` somewhere, you should see a response on the client side.

Comment: I have just post a res.send at the end of each function. The resquest is not pending, but the SQL statements are still slow and I need to kill the process and restart it to see the changes.

And in other function, I didn't put it , and I had no problem. so why ?

Comment: You should probably instead put `res.end()` inside your inner-most callback (the 'select' SQL query callback in this case) so that the response is only sent once the update and select queries have finished. If the client is expecting content in the response, you will need to pass that to `res.end()` (or use one of Express's helper methods like `res.json()` if you want to send a JSON response).